# Why is java.util.Currency.getDisplayName() returning null

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an application utilizing this class: `java.util.Currency`

In the application, I maintain a Map of country codes to locales. I retrieve a locale by passing in a country code

When I pass this locale to `Currency.getInstance()`, it returns the correct currency. I verified that by calling `Currency.getCurrencyCode()`

However when I call `getDisplayName()` on the same currency instance, it returns `null`

This behavior does not happen on my dev machine, only on my test server

Both my dev machine and server use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with:

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

The application runs inside tomcat

I could be missing something here

edit

```
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
```

...

```
public static Map<String, Locale> COUNTRY_TO_LOCALE_MAP;

public static void initCountryToLocaleMap() {
    if (COUNTRY_TO_LOCALE_MAP != null) {
        return;
    }

    COUNTRY_TO_LOCALE_MAP = new HashMap<String, Locale>();

    Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();

    for (Locale l : locales) {
        COUNTRY_TO_LOCALE_MAP.put(l.getCountry(), l);
    }
}

public static Locale getLocaleFromCountryCode(String countryCode) {
    if (countryCode == null) {
        return null;
    }

    initCountryToLocaleMap();

    Locale locale = COUNTRY_TO_LOCALE_MAP.get(countryCode);

    if (locale == null) {
        return new Locale("", countryCode);
    }

    return locale;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    initCountryToLocaleMap();

    String countryCode = "ZA";
    Locale locale = getLocaleFromCountryCode(countryCode);
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);

    System.out.println("currencyCode: " + currency.getCurrencyCode());
    System.out.println("displayName: " + currency.getDisplayName());
}
```

Upon running main(), i got the following output:
from dev machine:

```
currencyCode: ZAR
displayName: South African Rand
```

from test server:

```
currencyCode: ZAR
```

Comment: Please show code.  We can't help you without something concrete to look at

Comment: check the default locale on both of your server (DEV and TEST)

Comment: Are you sure that your dev and test machine use the same JDK version?

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) for the Currency class indicates that method `getDisplayName()` is new in version 1.7 of Java. Try running Tomcat with version 1.7 of the JDK.

I would be surprised if Tomcat just silently fails and returns null. Did you check in the Tomcat logs to see if there is any Exception?

Comment: That's weird. Shouldn't it be throwing `NoSuchMethodError` because the method was not found or `UnsupportedClassVersionError` since one tried to run a 1.7 class file with Java 1.6?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling:

```
Locale.getAvailableLocales();
```

To populate you `COUNTRY_TO_LOCALE_MAP` map with key as `country` and value as `Locale`.

**Problem is that there is no one-to-one mapping between all countries in the world and the locales.** e.g. You will get many Local entries with empty `country` in the list. You are inserting an empty key multiple times into your map as a result of that behavior.

**And yes the country you're looking up `ZA` is also not getting returned.** That is the reason you're getting null returned.

Locales actually represent regions. They are meant to mark things like language, currency etc.

Comment: How does this explain why he's getting a different result from the dev and test machine?

Comment: `ZA` not having any entry in `Locale` list is really the cause for `Why is java.util.Currency.getDisplayName() returning null`. Different  installations can return different Locale settings.

Comment: And why is it not returning null when run from a different server?

Comment: @DavidLevesque: I wish had full access to those servers to answer that.